# Search record by name in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have created this table in sq-lite

```
String TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = 
            "create table contacts(id integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null, fname text not null, regid integer unique not null,year text not null, email text not null, phone text not null, address text not null)";
```

and there is a method for searching record by name

```
public Cursor searchByName(String name)
    {

        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"id","name", "phone"},
"name="+name, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

now when i want to search record for uzair like this, i got an error.

```
open(); //open database;
 Cursor c=searchByName("uzair");
close();  //close database.
```

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You did not wrap your SQL string in quotes: `"name='"+name+"'"`
But really you should parametrize your query to protect your database from injection attacks:

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"id","name", "phone"}, 
        "name=?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
```

(If this is not the entire solution, you need to post your LogCat errors so we don't have to guess.)

---

**Addition**
You added this comment:

> `if(student_name.length()>0) { open(); Cursor c= searchByName(student_name); c.moveToFirst(); names=new String[c.getCount()]; for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) { names[i]=c.getString(1); } db.close(); }`

I *assume* that this code is not working somehow, but again I have to *guess*... Click ["edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13732750/edit) in the lower-left corner of your question to add this code and the *LogCat errors* to your original post.

Anyway, I can see that you are not using `moveToNext()` inside your loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) { 
    names[i]=c.getString(1); 
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: if(student_name.length()>0)
   {
   
     open();
  
   Cursor c= searchByName(student_name);
     
    c.moveToFirst();
   
   names=new String[c.getCount()];
   for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
   {
    names[i]=c.getString(1);
    
   }
   db.close();
   
    
   }